# JSLint validation for Javascript with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

I am using JavaScript patterns with JQuery. I want JSLint to validate my code with maximum code quality. I have below screen shot for JSLint option to enable. Someone tell me what option should I check when coding JavaScript with JQuery.

Please

[image: JSLint Options]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `assume a browser` checkbox and on the `Predefined` section, type `jQuery` and `$`.

Comment: Thanks. Should I enable any other check box as well for avoiding unnecessary code check?

Comment: @shahid no, the other options are not related to jQuery.