# Run JSlint from console with custom options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint, static-code-analysis, javascript-debugger

In a previous question [Run JSLint on a .js file from debugging console in chrome or firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11884224/1577343) I learned how to run JSLint from console or from node.

Is there a way to run JSLint (from the JavaScript code like in the answer given to the above mentioned question) **but with custom options**, for example for code that contains jQuery ([JSLint validation for Javascript with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10557583/1577343)) with the options *Assume a browser* and the option *Predefined section* with jQuery and $ as parameters?

Comment: From the docs: *"When JSLINT is called as a function, it accepts an `option` object parameter that allows you to determine the subset of JavaScript that is acceptable to you."*. The source code also contains information about how to call the function (v see the link below v).

Comment: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js

Comment: @FelixKling I found the quote that you gave at  http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#options  but no sample code and I don't see no code example, from what I read  I guess the object should be simple `parameters ={"browser":"true", "predifined:":["jQuery","$"]}` ? How do I give  this to JSLINT function?

Comment: @FelixKling I think I need to read much more on JSLint, maybe a book or something

Comment: Or maybe you like JSHint more, which has a better documentation IMHO: http://www.jshint.com/docs/ (and is often less frustrating).

Comment: @FelixKling Does it have the assign protection feature you mentioned in the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an object with the options as second parameter to `JSLINT`. Global variables can be defined as an array of strings and assigned to the `predef` property of said options object.

From the [JSLint source code](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js#L28-L42):

> `JSLINT` is a global function. It takes two parameters.
>
> ```
> var myResult = JSLINT(source, option);
> ```
>
> The first parameter is either a string or an array of strings. If it is a
>   string, it will be split on `'\n'` or `'\r'`. If it is an array of strings, it
>   is assumed that each string represents one line. The source can be a
>   JavaScript text, or HTML text, or a JSON text, or a CSS text.
>
> The second parameter is an optional object of options that control the
>   operation of JSLINT. Most of the options are booleans: They are all
>   optional and have a default value of false. One of the options, `predef`,
>   can be an array of names, which will be used to declare global variables,
>   or an object whose keys are used as global names, with a boolean value
>   that determines if they are assignable.

Comment: So  `option ={"browser":"true", "predef:":["jQuery","$"]}` should be correct? Also please can you expand a little * or an object whose keys are used as global names, with a boolean value that determines if they are assignable* ? this means if `"mylibrary":"false"` given to `predef` gives an warning if I try to do something like this `lib = mylibrary`?

Comment: Yes, that should work... try it ;) You are close with the second one, it means that you cannot overwrite the variables with some other value, i.e. you cannot do  `mylibrary = someOtherValue`.

Comment: Thanks this is what I looked for some time, I'll try it? how do i put the last option in the array `"predef":["jQuery","$", {"mylibrary":"false"}]`?

Comment: It appears to have to be either an array or object. So you could do `"predef": {"jQuery":true, ,"$":true, "mylibrary":"false"}`.